# How to return id users buy several months consecutive?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I get all `user_id` values from the data below, for all rows containing the same `user_id` value over *consecutive months* from a given start date in the `date` column.

For example, given the below table....

| date | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-11-01 | 13 |
| 2018-11-01 | 13 |
| 2018-11-01 | 14 |
| 2018-11-01 | 15 |
| 2018-12-01 | 13 |
| 2019-01-01 | 13 |
| 2019-01-01 | 14 |

...supposing I want to get the `user_id` values for consecutive months prior to (but not including) `2019-01-01` then I'd have this as my output:

| user_id | m_year |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 2018-11 |
| 13 | 2018-12 |
| 13 | 2019-01 |

probably can be applied windows function

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What is the exact type of your `date` column? Does the data represent individual days or just months?

Comment: date column have type "date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to aggregate on a user and the year-months

```
select 
 t.user_id, 
 to_char(date_trunc('month',t.date),'YYYY-MM') as m_year
from yourtable t
where t.date < '2019-02-01'::date
group by t.user_id, date_trunc('month',t.date)
order by t.user_id, m_year
```

But if you only want those with consecutive months, then a little extra is needed.

```
select 
 user_id, 
 to_char(ym,'YYYY-MM') as m_year
from
(
  select t.user_id
  , date_trunc('month',t.date) as ym
  , lag(date_trunc('month',t.date)) 
   over (partition by t.user_id order by date_trunc('month',t.date)) as prev_ym
  , lead(date_trunc('month',t.date)) 
   over (partition by t.user_id order by date_trunc('month',t.date)) as next_ym
  from yourtable t
  where t.date < '2019-02-01'::date
  group by t.user_id, date_trunc('month',t.date)
) q
where (ym - prev_ym <= '31 days'::interval or 
       next_ym - ym <= '31 days'::interval)
order by user_id, ym
```

> ```
> user_id | m_year 
> ------: | :------
>      13 | 2018-11
>      13 | 2018-12
>      13 | 2019-01
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4a1b805c60d48b58a5c2dda3db576fef)*

Comment: I need get all users not only user 13

Comment: @spacenew Check out the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a `window function` in this specific query. Just try :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) user_id, date_trunc('month', date :: date) AS m_year
  FROM your_table
```

Comment: Window functions are needed to detect and filter consecutive months - right now your query doesn't return _only_ consecutive months leading-up-to `2019-01-01`.